# Passing parameters by reference? Let me fix that for you

Tags: c#, rubberduck

I've implemented a code inspection that verifies whether a procedure has parameters that are implicitly passed by reference - in VBA a parameter is passed `ByRef` unless it's explicitly specified `ByVal`.

Here is the implementation in question:

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ImplicitByRefParameterInspection : IInspection
{
    public ImplicitByRefParameterInspection()
    {
        Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Warning;
    }

    public string Name { get { return "Parameter is passed ByRef implicitly"; } }
    public CodeInspectionType InspectionType { get { return CodeInspectionType.CodeQualityIssues; } }
    public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }

    public IEnumerable<CodeInspectionResultBase> GetInspectionResults(SyntaxTreeNode node)
    {
        var procedures = node.FindAllProcedures().Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value)));
        var targets = procedures.Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
                                                && !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline);

        return targets.SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
            .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity)));
    }
}
```

Would there be a better way to do this? Here is the `ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult` class (gosh that's a long name!):

```
[ComVisible(false)]
public class ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult : CodeInspectionResultBase
{
    public ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(string inspection, Instruction instruction, CodeInspectionSeverity type)
        : base(inspection, instruction, type)
    {
    }

    public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
    {
        return !Handled
            ? new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
                {
                    {"Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal},
                    {"Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef}
                }
            : new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>();
    }

    private void PassParameterByRef(VBE vbe)
    {
        if (!Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
        {
            var newContent = string.Concat(ReservedKeywords.ByRef, " ", Instruction.Value);
            var oldContent = Instruction.Line.Content;

            var result = oldContent.Replace(Instruction.Value, newContent);

            var module = vbe.FindCodeModules(Instruction.Line.ProjectName, Instruction.Line.ComponentName).First();
            module.ReplaceLine(Instruction.Line.StartLineNumber, result);
            Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // todo: implement for multiline
            throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not [yet] implemented for multiline instructions.");
        }
    }

    private void PassParameterByVal(VBE vbe)
    {
        if (!Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
        {
            var newContent = string.Concat(ReservedKeywords.ByVal, " ", Instruction.Value);
            var oldContent = Instruction.Line.Content;

            var result = oldContent.Replace(Instruction.Value, newContent);

            var module = vbe.FindCodeModules(Instruction.Line.ProjectName, Instruction.Line.ComponentName).First();
            module.ReplaceLine(Instruction.Line.StartLineNumber, result);
            Handled = true;
        }
        else
        {
            // todo: implement for multiline
            throw new NotImplementedException("This method is not yet implemented for multiline instructions.");
        }
    }
}
```

Any comment is welcome.

Comment: Is `IInspection` under your control? And is `CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; set; }` part of the interface?

Comment: @TopinFrassi yes, and yes :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Starting from this

```
var procedures = node.FindAllProcedures().Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value)));
var targets = procedures.Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
                                        && !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline);

return targets.SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
    .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity)));
```

Let's collapse it into one expression

```
return node.FindAllProcedures()
    .Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value)))
    .Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
                                        && !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
    .SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
    .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity)));
```

Move the last `Select` out of `SelectMany`

```
return node.FindAllProcedures()
    .Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value)))
    .Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
                                        && !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
    .SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters)
    .Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
    .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity));
```

Now it seems like `procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)` is redundant, so let's remove that and join the successive `Where`s

```
return node.FindAllProcedures()
    .Where(procedure => procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value))
                        && !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
    .SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters)
    .Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
    .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity));
```

It's not clear why `procedure.Parameters.Any(parameter => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter.Instruction.Value))` is necessary -- if it is, a comment is required, otherwise we can just write

```
return node.FindAllProcedures()
    .Where(procedure => !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline)
    .SelectMany(procedure => procedure.Parameters)
    .Where(parameter => parameter.IsImplicitByRef)
    .Select(parameter => new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity));
```

Which is looking more much manageable. Or if you prefer the alternative syntax

```
return from procedure in node.FindAllProcedures()
       where !procedure.Instruction.Line.IsMultiline
       from parameter in procedure.Parameters
       where parameter.IsImplicitByRef
       select new ImplicitByRefParameterInspectionResult(Name, parameter.Instruction, Severity);
```

Answer (score 14):

I don't know how I feel about this ternary.

> ```
> public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
> {
>     return !Handled
>         ? new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
>             {
>                 {"Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal},
>                 {"Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef}
>             }
>         : new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>();
> }
> ```

I mean, it really could be worse and I admittedly don't like ternaries beyond *very* simple assignments. I feel like an `if` statement is called for here. Even though it will add a few lines of code, I think it would add to the readability. On the other hand, for the mess it *could have been*, it wasn't. Well done. I don't hate it. (Did I mention that I hate ternaries?)

How I would write it.

```
public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
{
    var result = new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>;

    if (!Handled)
    {
        result.Add("Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal);
        result.Add("Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef);
    }

    return result;
}
```

There are pros and cons to each method. My way reduces the level of indentation, but introduces an intermediate variable

> Hmm.. that ternary is in every implementation.... –  [Mat's Mug](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/74005/passing-parameters-by-reference-let-me-fix-that-for-you#comment134502_74007)

I think `GetQuickFixes` in the *base* class should take a dictionary in as an argument. Then this logic doesn't need to be in every implementation. It just needs to create the proper dict for the unhandled case, pass it to base, and return whatever dictionary the base deems necessary. That way this logic doesn't need to be implemented over and over again.  You should end up with something that looks like this.

```
public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
{
    var fixes = new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
         {
             {"Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal},
             {"Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef}
         } 
    return base.GetQuickFixes(fixes);
}
```

And *now* the ternary becomes acceptable in the base class.

```
public IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes(IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> actions)
{
    return !Handled ? actions : new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>();
}
```

Comment: Hmm.. that ternary is in *every implementation*....

Comment: It's honestly not that bad. Just a pet peeve and I'm sure for every person who agrees with me, there will be two who don't.

Comment: Personally i would rearrange the ternary but keep it as a ternary, because you know it's a hammer.

Comment: I like this. It creates the return value only once.

Comment: Okay. Last edit I think. Had another idea. It bothered me that the same logic was in every implementation.

Comment: The best part is that when an inspection is acted upon, the project gets re-parsed and so `Handled` can be dropped altogether...

Answer (score 12):

> ```
> public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
> {
>     return !Handled
>         ? new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
>             {
>                 {"Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal},
>                 {"Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef}
>             }
>         : new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>();
> }
> ```

With this I would turn this around, so that I could use `Handled` instead of 
not handled...

so it would look something like this

```
public override IDictionary<string, Action<VBE>> GetQuickFixes()
{
    return Handled
        ? new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>()
        : new Dictionary<string, Action<VBE>>
            {
                {"Pass parameter by value", PassParameterByVal},
                {"Pass parameter by reference explicitly", PassParameterByRef}
            };
}
```

Answer (score 11):

> ```
> var newContent = string.Concat(ReservedKeywords.ByVal, " ", Instruction.Value);
> ```

Here's a nifty thing I learned recently:

```
var newContent = ReservedKeywords.ByVal + " " + Instruction.Value;
```

will be optimized by the compiler to a call to `string.Concat`, exactly the same as above. It's also more readable, so you have nothing to lose. You can read more about it on [Eric Lippert's blog](http://ericlippert.com/2013/06/17/string-concatenation-behind-the-scenes-part-one/).

---

The methods `PassParameterByRef` and `PassParameterByVal` are identical except for one variable, and could (unless you're planning on changing them) just call in to a common method.

Answer (score 6):

I'm not sure about the fact that `Severity` is `public set`. As a client of your code, who am I to say that `ImplicitByRefParameterInspection` has a severity of X when you, as the dev, who knows his stuff, said it had a severity of `Warning`.

I think your interface should expose only the getter on `CodeInspectionSeverity Severity`.

I'm not part of the project but I have a hard time to see a scenario where you would want to `set` the severity of an `IInspection`. Since it is an abstraction, you can't tell how severe it is.

(I think) You want to set the severity of an implementation of `IInspection`.

If I turn this into code, it would look like this :

```
public interface IInspection
{
    CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; }
}

[ComVisible(false)]
public class ImplicitByRefParameterInspection : IInspection
{
    public ImplicitByRefParameterInspection()
    {
        Severity = CodeInspectionSeverity.Warning;
    }

    public CodeInspectionSeverity Severity { get; private set; }
}
```

This way, I (as a client) can know the severity of an inspection, but I can't `set` it, and it is a good thing, since I have absolutely no clue what it should be.

Comment: I should have included the enum in the post.. it goes from `DoNotShow` to `Error` - it's intended to be configurable by the dev using it - if you want to show an inspection type as a "hint", as a "suggestion" or as a "warning", or if you just don't want to see it, you can configure that. The user (VBA/COM) doesn't see that type, and cannot access it programmatically.

Comment: +1 Because your answer makes sense given the context, but in fact there is a [configuration that lets the user specify what the severity level should be](https://github.com/retailcoder/Rubberduck/blob/settingsUI/RetailCoder.VBE/App.cs#L72-L84)].

Comment: I wasn't sure at the moment I wrote my answer, but I thought it could be useful anyway! :)